# Is there a way to filter out rows from a table with an unnamed column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm currently trying to do analysis of rolling correlations of a dataset with four compared values but only need the output of rows containing 'a'

I got my data frame by using the command `newdf = df.rolling(3).corr()`

Sample input (random numbers)

```
    a b c d 
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
2 a
2 b
2 c
2 d
3 a 
3 b   5 6 3
3 c   4 3 1 
3 d   3 4 2
4 a 1 3 5 6 
4 b 6 2 4 1 
4 c 8 6 6 7 
4 d 2 5 4 6 
5 a 2 5 4 1 
5 b 1 4 6 3
5 c 2 6 3 7
5 d 3 6 3 7
```

and need the output

```
    a b c d
1 a 1 3 5 6
2 a 2 5 4 1
```

I've tried filtering it by doing `adf = newdf.filter(['a'], axis=0)` however that gets rid of everything and when doing it for the other axis it filters by column. Unfortunately the column containing the rows with values: a, b, c, d is unnamed so I cant filter that column individually. This wouldn't be an issue however if its possible to flip the rows and columns with the values being listed by index to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `loc`. Put the column of `abcdabcd ...` as index and just use `loc`

```
df.loc['a']
```

Comment: I tried to do that but but the column of abcdabcd has no column name so I don’t know how to assign it

Answer (score 0):

The actual source of problem in your case is that your DataFrame
has a **Multi**Index.

So when you attempt to execute `newdf.filter(['a'], axis=0)` you want
to leave rows with the index containing **only** "a" string.

But since your DataFrame has a MultiIndex, each row with "a" at
level *1* contains also some number at level *0*.

To get your intended result, run:

```
newdf.filter(like='a', axis=0)
```

maybe followed by *.dropna()*.

An alterantive solution is:

```
newdf.xs('a', level=1, drop_level=False)
```